# Editing contents of a labview array

Tags: labview

I'm trying to increment specific elements by 1, in order to log results as they come in. I'm trying to read an element, add 1 to it, and then write it back to the same memory address. Why isn't this simple?

In code it would be something as simple as;

```
array1[element1] = (array1[element1]+1)
```

or

```
array1[element1]++
```

Arrays seem to be either read (indicators) or write (controls)? This is really frustrating, and there's very little help online.

Comment: Arrays are collections of data in memory; they're represented on the Block Diagram as wires.  You can act on an array in memory with the Array function nodes using the wire.  The control/indicator is only a user interface element.

Comment: It's perhaps helpful to think of the *wires* as the variables, and the front panel controls and indicators as accessors that just make a copy of those variables.

Answer (score 5):

You can use an "Array index/replace" element inside a "In place element structure":

[image: usage of in place element structure]

Comment: This increments the contents of an array constant and places it into a new array.

How do I have the input and output as the same array?

Comment: See my comment to your original post; I think you're confused about data-flow programming because it sounds like you're using Front Panel objects as variables.  Unless you're talking about in-place memory operations to optimize memory use, you should think of your data as flowing along a wire rather than an array as an entity in itself.  Unless you're talking about OOP...

Comment: It's not necessary to use the In Place Element structure unless you're particularly concerned about NOT making a copy of the array in memory, is it? I'm pretty sure this is only something you should use if profiling your code shows you have a memory or speed issue. Just use Replace Array Subset as Mike Benza suggests.

Answer (score 4):

You should use ReplaceArraySubset in the Array palette.  For simple replacements, it's much faster than the In Place Element Structure
[image: Replace Array Subset example.]

Answer (score -2):

As an infrequent, novice Labview user I have the same problem ... until I found the code that I used 10 years ago.  Surely the answer to sgccarey is:-
Right click on the array control or indicator and 'create local variable'
This variable will appear on the block diagram and can be set as 'Change to Write' or 'Change to Read' as necessary to use as the input and / or output array to a simple 'replace array subset'.
This way the array data only appears once on the Front Panel and is updated as required.
I have no idea if using Local Variables affects runtime efficiency but it works for me. Hope this helps.

Comment: Local variables should be avoided as it makes data flow difficult to read, instead use a wire from the control, and plug it into "replace array subset"